# OLEDB Exception From CSV to Datatable

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I have following Code to export data From CSV to Datatable

```
 string cnstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=CSVFilePath;Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\";";
            string sql = "SELECT A,B,C,D FROM Csvfile.csv";

            using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnstr))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
            }
```

But Getting Error as **The value of the parameters that are required of one or more has not been set**

Query looks Ok for me. As all columns are available in CSV file. Even I tried
**string sql = "SELECT [A],[B],[C],[D] FROM Csvfile.csv";**

But no Luck.

How to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to recommend this as an alternative for reading CSV files

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Answer (score 0):

If you define a model class to match what data types you want for your DataTable columns you can use something like this:

```
public static DataTable CSVToDataTable(string pathToCsv, bool csvHasHeader, Type csvSchema)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                var props = csvSchema.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
                }
                foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToCsv).Skip(csvHasHeader ? 1 : 0))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(CSVLinetoDataRow(line, dt));
                }
                return dt;
            }

private static object[] CSVLinetoDataRow(string csvLine, DataTable dt)
        {
            //remove commas within quotation marks
            var regex = new Regex("\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
            string[] values = regex.Replace(csvLine, m => m.Value.Replace(',', ':')).Split(',');

            object[] arr = new object[values.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt.Columns[i].DataType);
                if (values[i] != "\"\"") 
                {
                    arr[i] = converter.ConvertFrom(values[i].Replace("\"", ""));
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[i] = null;
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
```